# How does youtube offline works. How to make this feature to our own app

Tags: video, youtube, offline

How does youtube offline feature works. How to implement this feature in my app.

Where to learn this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is possibility to work offline with youtube? All I can think that you can do is to download the song or movie or whatever you want from youtube and store it on your server and then just playing it as mp4  video file or mp3 with html5 video player.

**Be aware- as part as I know this action is not legal.**

Comment: I think you misunderstood wrongly. I am saying about the youtube app, Where we can save the video to offline and watch. I am asking how youtube implemented this. Can we also do(code) the same functionality.